# how to popup a video on click to a view block title using colorbox trigger?

Tags: views, javascript

i have created a view block to display video titles, now how to popup a video on click to the title in a block using colorbox?. path to the video folder is (default/files/default/videos).

Comment: Have a look at this https://www.drupal.org/node/1994322 . Hope this helps